# datatable no se ajusta al colapsar el sidebar

Tags: jquery, datatable

al colapsar el menú lateral, el dataTable no se ajusta al nuevo ancho.
[image: antes de colapsar]

[image: despues de colapsar]

```css
#tamano {
 width: 90% !important;

}

.desact {
background:  #91A3B0;
}


#verTodo .modal-body{
  height: 363px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h2.titulolibro613 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', "Adobe Blank"; font-style: italic;
}

.cep{
 font-size: 13px
}

.alto {
    line-height: 13px;
    width: 170px; 
}

.p-5s{
 padding-bottom: 3px !important;
}

.xxx{
 padding-right: 0!important;
 width: 130px;
}
.xx{
 padding-left: 7px!important;
 
}

div.especial .col-md-12{
 padding-right: 0!important;
 padding-left:  0!important;
}

tfoot input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

th.dt-center, td.dt-center { text-align: center; }



.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 70px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 15px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 23px; padding: 0; line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 13px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "Sin Nov";
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "Con Nov";
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 13px; margin: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 43px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<?php 
        include_once 'funciones/bd_conexion.php';
        include_once 'templates/head.php';
        include_once 'templates/header.php';
        include_once 'templates/asidebar.php';
        include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';

        $mostrar="";
        if ($_SESSION['permiso']!=2) {

              $mostrar = "WHERE estado = 0"; 
               
             } else{
              $mostrar = "";
             }



        $sql = "SELECT * FROM control";
        $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
        $resultado2 = $conn->query($sql);

        $sql99 ="SELECT idcontrol, count(estado) FROM controlunidad where estado=0 and idcontrol=99 group by idcontrol";


      ?>  

       <?php 
                        if ($_SESSION['permiso']==4) {
                          $ver="inline";
                        }else {
                          $ver="none";
                        }

                         ?>
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper" id=""> <!-- al id recargar -->
      <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
      <section class="content-header">

        <div class="container" id="">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="display: <?php echo $ver; ?>" onclick="nuevocontrolx()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nuevo C-E&nbsp</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <h2 class="titulolibro613" align=""><b>RESUMEN GENERAL DE CONTROL DE EQUIPOS</b></h2> 
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

      <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content container-fluid">

        



        <div class="box" id=""><!-- antes este id se llamaba tablaServiciosComandancia-->
             
              <!-- /.box-header -->
              <div class="box-body" id="recarga">
                <table id="example8" class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Motivo</th>
                    <th>Tot.0-8</th>
                    <th>Con-Nov</th>
                    <th>Realizado-Por</th>
                    
                    
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="recargartabla">
                
                    <?php 
                    while ($rows = $resultado->fetch_array()) {?>
                        
                    <tr id="aqui">
                      <td><a href="uncontrol.php?idcontrol=<?php echo $rows['idcontrol']?>&fecha=<?php echo $rows['fecha'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['idcontrol'] ?></a></td>
                      <td><?php echo $rows['fecha']?></td>
                      <td><?php if($rows['horaControl']==1) {
                        echo '8:15';
                      }elseif ($rows['horaControl']==2) {
                        echo '12:15';
                      }else {
                        echo 'No-Realizado';
                      }
                      ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $rows['motivo'] ?></td>
                      <td>
                        <?php
                        $id = $rows['idcontrol'];
                        $res = "SELECT idcontrol, count(estado) AS estados FROM controlunidad where estado=0 and idcontrol= $id group by idcontrol";
                        $res1 = $conn->query($res);
                        $res2 = $res1->fetch_array();
                        echo ($res2['estados']>0) ? $res2['estados'] : "-";
                        
                        ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php
                        $id = $rows['idcontrol'];
                        $res = "SELECT idcontrol, count(novedad) AS novedades FROM controlunidad where novedad=1 and idcontrol= $id group by idcontrol";
                        $res1 = $conn->query($res);
                        $res2 = $res1->fetch_array();
                        echo ($res2['novedades']>0) ? $res2['novedades'] : "-";
                        
                        ?>

                      </td>
                      <td><?php echo $rows['creadopor'];?></td>
                      
                    </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                 
               
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                  
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Motivo</th>
                    <th>Tot.0-8</th>
                    <th>Con-Nov</th>
                    <th>Realizado-Por</th>
                    
                    
                  </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                
                </table>
              </div>
              
            </div>

              <!-- /.box-body -->

    </section>

<script>
  function nuevocontrolx(){
    window.location.href = "controlEquipos.php";
}


  function verservicios(id){
    
  $("#cambioEstado").load('ver-detalle.php',{
    id:id
  });
$("#cambioEstado").modal('show');

}

 function crearserviciocomandancia(){
    
  $("#setServicio").load('nuevo-serv-comandancia.php',{
    
  });
$("#setServicio").modal('show');

}


function editarservcomandancia(id){
  $("#setServicio").load('edit-serv-comandancia.php',{
    id:id
  });
  $("#setServicio").modal('show');

}

function cambioestadoserviciocomandancia(id){
  console.log(id);
  $("#estadoServicio").load('cambio-estado-ser-comandancia.php',{
     id:id
  });
  $("#estadoServicio").modal('show');
}

</script>
 
  <!--...........................................................................................-->
</div>


  <?php 
      include_once 'templates/footer.php';
      include_once 'templates/modales/modales.php';
   
        
  ?>
```

AHORA mi CODIGO DE LA TABLA

```js
<script>
  $(function () {
   
    $('#example8').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false,
      "scrollY"     : "300px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      "language"    :{"search":"Buscar", "zeroRecords":"Sin Resultados Coincidentes"},
      
      "columnDefs": [
          {targets:1, render:function(data){return moment(data).format('DD/MMM/YY')}}, 
          {className: "dt-center", targets: '_all' },
          
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel', 'pdf', 'print', {extend:'colvis',text:"Mostra/ocultar Columnas"}
        ]   
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta con el código completo. Pienso que este es un error de CSS; pero, sin el código completo, es difícil dar una conclusión.

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave listo....código completo, perdón por lo desordenado del codigo

Comment: ¿colocaste el código CSS?

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave ya ahora también subi el css

Comment: jonathan,. gracias por editar la pregunta, sin embargo, creo que está incompleta. he creado este [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/Lstzkrf9/1/) con tu código *(removiendo cierta lógica de PHP que tenías)* y veo que los estilos no se aplican. ¿estás seguro que este es el código completo? Yo insisto que este es un problema de CSS...

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave
 mis estilos al menos en mi proyecto si se aplican, no creo que no lo podre solucionar .-(

Comment: no diga eso :) debe tener alguna solución, es cuestión de seguir intentando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola han pasado como dos años y dos meses, pero tal vez sirva esta respuesta para otro usuario que pueda necesitar. La solución es indicar en la tabla que usas para asignar el datatable poner el atributo width al 100% y el espacio que aparece (como en mi  caso el espacio me aparece a los costados) se ajusta a la tabla y se arregla el problema:

```
<table style="width:100%" ... >
```

Espero le sirva esta solución a alguien como a mi me sirvió.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Creo que la respuesta en este caso, no consigue solucionar lo que preguntan, Puedes comprobarlo en el enlace que se ha puesto a jsfiddle, implementando tú propuesta. No obstante lo más importante del comentario, es que te puede ayudar realizar el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y leer [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente el problema de este caso era un div que se encontraba mal cerrado...;)